# How to preview or display or edit an Excel file on web page by C# and .NET framework

Tags: c#, excel, html

Working on a task that displaying or previewing an excel file, which generated by EPPlus, on web page (.aspx).

Now, my problem is all the source point to the keywords: excel web app, excel web service, sharepoint or Excel online, but when i dug into those keywords i lose myself. Most of the information are about how to    do the task inside the excel, such as save as html, publish to sharepoint etc.  And the rest of the information are delivered by brain-unfriendly example or language.

So I am wondering can someone give me a walk-through method about publishing or displaying or previewing  or editing an Excel file on web page(.aspx) by C# language and .NET framework.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to save the excel file on the webserver then have a link to download the file -- edit in excel and upload it to the webserver

Comment: Hi, Hogan, I have built the function to download the excel. But in some cases, our customer don't install the Office, so we hope to provide an option to preview or display then in excel online or something else.

Comment: Well you could try to rewrite excel from scratch -- I don't think that would be so easy.   Seems to me like your application requires excel or open office installed locally to work.

Comment: I re-read your question... if you are generating via EPPlus then you could generate HTML or PDF at the same time.

Comment: I used to search about it. Seems like, The EPPlus is not parsing the HTML at this moment. Do you have any link or source about it? Thanks.

Comment: That comment / questions makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can't natively modify Excel files in web browsers. Browsers can support some files such as Java Applets or Adobe Flash, but those requires plugins, and they don't exist for Excel files.

Instead, you should create an HTML representation of the Excel file, and allow the user to then manipulate the HTML representation. When they're done, generate an Excel file based on their changes.

Alternatively, allow the user to download the Excel file and make their changes, and allow them to publish the changes back to the server by uploading the file.

Comment: Thanks, Mason. To creat a HTML representation is not an option for me, I have charts, tables in the excel. What I want is to build a link, which send and open the excel file to excel online or excel web app, in our .aspx page code.

Comment: Like I said, you can't natively do that in browsers. You'll have to use an external tool. You mentioned a few options in your question. You should investigate them. Stack Overflow is not a place to come to for tool recommendations.